# How would I sort Emojis to be in front of the alphabet?

Tags: ios, swift, nsarray, emoji

In Swift, I have an array of strings... Emojis can be in these strings.

As it stands, the emojis get sorted to the very end, but I want them to get sorted to the front.

How would I achieve this?

Right now I do...

`array.sort({$0 < $1})`.

I've thought about using a Regex to see if the value isn't any regular character on the keyboard but was hoping for a better solution.

Comment: Do you have emojis mixed with alphabet characters?

Comment: Yes, I've character with emojis.

Answer (score -1):

Here is how you can do it in Swift:

```
array = array.sorted(by: { $0.localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare($1) == .orderedAscending })
```

where

```
var array: [String]
```

Answer (score -3):

Since Emojis are unicode, you can just make a [list of them](http://apps.timwhitlock.info/emoji/tables/unicode), check if the character is in the list, and order it accordingly.